# Using a Python script to start and stop the Google App Engine dev_appserver during continuous integration testing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to write a Python script that will enable me to start the Google App Engine dev_appserver using coverage.py, fetch the /test url from the app that I launch, wait for the server to finish returning the page, then shutdown the dev_appserver, and then generate a report.

My challenge is how to launch the dev_appserver in the background so that I can do the http fetch and then how to shut down the dev_appserver before generating my report.

I'm heading towards something like this:

```
# get_gae_coverage.py
# Launch dev_appserver with coverge.py
coverage run --source=./ /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore --use_sqlite .
#Fetch /test
urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/test').read()
# Shutdown dev_appserver somehow
# ??
# Generate coverage report
coverage report
```

What is the best way to write a python script to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go with [subprocess Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

coverage_proc = subprocess.Popen(
          ['coverage','run', your_flag_list]
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
time.sleep(5) #Find the correct sleep value
urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/test').read()
time.sleep(1)
os.kill(coverage_proc.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

[Here](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/runsamples.py) you can find another approach to test if the server is up and running:

```
line = proc.stdout.readline()
while '] Running application' not in line:
     line = proc.stdout.readline()
```

Answer (score 2):

`threading` is the way to accomplish such a kind of task. Namely, you start the dev_appserver in a thread or in the main thread and as it is running, run and collect the results using the coverage module and then kill the dev_appserver python process in another thread and you will have results from coverage.

Here is sample snippet, which runs the `dev_appserver.py` in a thread and then waits for 10 seconds before and then it kills the python process. You can modify the end method in a suitable wherein the instead of waiting for 10 seconds, it waits for few seconds (in order to  let the python process start) and then start doing the coverage testing and after it is done, kill the appserver and finish coverage.

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time

hold_process = []

def start():
    print 'In the start process'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python','dev_appserver.py','yourapp'])
    hold_process.append(proc)

def end():
    time.sleep(10)
    proc = hold_process.pop(0)
    print 'Killing the appserver process'
    proc.kill()


t = threading.Thread(name='startprocess',target=start)
t.deamon = True
w = threading.Thread(name='endprocess',target=end)
t.start()
w.start()
t.join()
w.join()
```

Comment: the OP is trying to launch the dev_appserver with coverage run.

Comment: @systempuntout - yes, I got it. if my understanding is not wrong. You run dev_appserver in one thread and then run the coverage in another thread and then coordinate, correct? That was my answer.